# Digital Signature with ECDSA c#

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, jwt

In section 3.4 "Digital Signature with ECDSA" of:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518

It states that:

> The ECDSA P-256 SHA-256 digital signature is generated as follows:
>
> 1. Generate a digital signature of the JWS Signing Input using ECDSA
>    P-256 SHA-256 with the desired private key.  The output will be
>    the pair (R, S), where R and S are 256-bit unsigned integers.
> 2. Turn R and S into octet sequences in big-endian order, with each
>    array being be 32 octets long.  The octet sequence
>    representations MUST NOT be shortened to omit any leading zero
>    octets contained in the values.
> 3. Concatenate the two octet sequences in the order R and then S.
>    (Note that many ECDSA implementations will directly produce this
>    concatenation as their output.)
> 4. The resulting 64-octet sequence is the JWS Signature value.

I want to do just that, sign a jwt with a private key and ES256 algorithm, but I'm having a lot o trouble just in the first step:

> Generate a digital signature of the JWS Signing Input using ECDSA
> P-256 SHA-256 with the desired private key. The output will be the
> pair (R, S), where R and S are 256-bit unsigned integers.

Can someone help me with an example of this in .net?